# Need to publish raster layers with WFS in QGIS Server, but not available

Tags: raster, layers, wfs, qgis-server

In a QGIS project, I have several raster layers---satellite imagery for specific areas--and I wish to serve these via QGIS Server.  WMS works nicely, and they show up for WCS.  But I cannot see the layers in WFS, which is required.  Nor do they show up as FeatureTypes in GetCapabailities, nor can I see them in the configuration for the project (1st screen capture). The layer properties are also set, as I expect they'd need (2nd image).

What am I missing?

[image: Setup]

[image]

Comment: WFS is for vectors, for raster you need a WCS

Comment: Who is setting the requirement to have raster data served as a WFS?

Answer (score 1):

> What am I missing?

By definition, it's not possible to serve raster data through a Web Feature Service.  If you want to access the raster data you need to use a Web Coverage Service

Comment: I know of at least one GIS (OSSIM) that seems do raster imagery in WFS.  But thanks.  Did not see this caveat anywhere in the QGIS or WFS documentation.